# QGIS 3.22.16: Sometimes projects do not open completely

Tags: qgis, wms

Since QGIS version 3.22.16 I have the following problem (that did not occur in 3.22.15):

Sometimes a bigger project (> 100 Layer) does not open completely, I see the Layer-Window on the left side, but no map. QGIS "freezes". I have to close it "with violence".

When I open a smaller project, this problem does not occur. And when I open the bigger project directly after the small project (without finishing QGIS), then also the bigger project opens without problems.

But even when the bigger project is open, and I want to close it, QGIS says "QGIS does not answer", even for several minutes, then I have to close it with violence again. My OS is ubuntu 22.04. The projects are saved as qgz.

I tried creating a new profile. Sometimes it works better, sometimes not.

Now I could isolate the problem:
I started QGIS with the ubuntu-terminal, and then opened the problematic QGIS-project. I could find out, that the origin of the problem are 2 WMS-layers. When I remove them from the project, everything works fine, but with these WMS-layers QGIS freezes while opening. I tried to embed these WMS layers once more, but it does not help. And this problem did not occur with the same project under QGIS 3.22.15.
And another crazy observation: the problem does not occur, when I start the QGIS-project with double-click on the project file (instead of opening QGIS and then starting the project).
Has anybody an idea?